# Django unsupported operand type for instancemethod and decimal

Tags: django, methods, model

I have a model function that calls another model function and performs a computation with the result. The result returned should be a decimal however I'm getting an error:

`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'instancemethod' and 'Decimal'`

I've tried `Decimal()` to convert the return but that resulted in the same error but saying that I couldn't convert instancemethod to decimal.

The relevant code is:

```
cimt = member.cimt

bal = cimt - cpp

if bal == 0:
    pass
elif bal < 0:
    owes_members.append(member)
elif bal > 0:
    owed_members.append(member)
    record_item = ReceiptItem(member = member, amount = bal)
    record_item.save()
    print record_item.amount
```

The line where the error occurs is `bal = cimt - cpp`

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please show more code. Its too hard to guess what is happening :P

Comment: I'm not sure what else is relevant, it seems like a really trivial issue. I'll put up some more code.

Comment: Well, please read the question for yourself as someone who has no context of what is going on. Your question makes no sense. What is really useful is what `member.cimt` is and what `cpp` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error tells you you're trying to perform a computation with the model method, not the result of calling the method.  It should be:

```
cimt = member.cimt()
```

Or called with whatever arguments you need.

You can access and manipulate methods by name just like anything else on an object; you need to use the parentheses to actually call it.